# Why does ffmpeg return a different framecount than ffprobe for the same file?

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I'm trying to count the number of frames in a video but ffmpeg and ffprobe are giving me two different answers.

```
$ time ffprobe -v error -count_frames -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=nb_read_frames -of default=nokey=1:noprint_wrappers=1 myvideo.mp4
2858

real    0m2.987s
user    0m2.740s
sys     0m0.172s
```

When I check the same file with ffmpeg I get 2 more frames...

```
$ time ffmpeg -y -i myvideo.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f null /dev/null 2>&1 | grep 'frame=' | awk '{print $2}'
2860

real    0m0.127s
user    0m0.080s
sys     0m0.032s
```

I used ffprobe to output all of the frames and count the number of "[FRAME]"s in the resultant output...

```
ffprobe -i myvideo.mp4 -show_frames -v error | grep -o '\[FRAME\]' | wc -l
2858
```

Which as you can see shows the number ffprobe thought there were.

Obviously I would prefer to use ffmpeg here because it is significantly faster than ffprobe and I am dealing with thousands of videos that need parsing and indexing. However the failure isn't consistent across multiple videos; sometimes it's 1 out, other times it's 2 or more...

Unfortunately, I have been counting frames for the past two years using the ffmpeg method, so I have a significant library of videos to reprocess now ... he gulps... I guess its a good way to verify the readability of the files on the cluster... even so, its going to take probably a few weeks to recalculate all of the existing video frame sizes.

Comment: Can you provide a small input file so we can give it a try?

Comment: Sure thing... I have uploaded an utterly uninteresting video to https://securitgroup.com/mp4/trouble.mp4... (someone turned out the lights).

Comment: I get `2858` with `ffmpeg -i trouble.mp4 -f null -`. Sounds like you have an older version of ffmpeg.

In any case, the number your ffmpeg is producing is the same as that stored in the `stsz` box of the file, and includes frames dropped by the edit list stored in the file. You can get the same number in ffprobe by looking at `nb_frames` with `-show_streams`.

Comment: Pretty sure I have the current stable release of ffmpeg which I installed last week, I will verify in the morning. Thanks

Comment: ffprobe version 3.4.1-1~16.04.york0 and ffmpeg version 3.4.1-1~16.04.york0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Mulvya was correct. I was able to get a consistent number by using FFprobe to query the nb_frames. By default ffprobe uses -count_frames which literally starts at the top of the file and counts the number of frames all the way to the bottom of the file. This is, of course, quite a slow operation, especially if the video file is quite large (which mine tend to be).

```
time ./ffprobe -v error -count_frames -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=nb_read_frames -of default=nokey=1:noprint_wrappers=1 big.mp4
real    1m4.531s
user    0m7.172s
sys     0m0.104s
```

FFmpeg writes to the stsz box, the number of frames it thinks is in the file when (in my case) it is converted from another format. So, I chose to use the value in stsz because although it is not correct, it is consistent and very quick to query

```
time ffprobe -v quiet -pretty  -select_streams v:0 -show_entries "stream=nb_frames" big.mp4
real    0m0.023s
user    0m0.040s
sys     0m0.008s
```

Thanks Mulvya!